# Video unavailable when loading from Azure Video Indexer API

Tags: azure-video-indexer

I am having problems with indexing a video, If I try to load a video with a URL from the Azure media service, Video Indexer throws error and abruptly fails indexing with error message "Video Unavailable", this happens if I load it with the API or directly in videoindexer.ai, does anyone have any idea how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video Indexer (VI) expect to have a direct URL for the video itself. So, when you put the URL in your browser the video should start download/play

Can you please elaborate more about how you generate the URL in Azure Media Services (AMS)? For example, are you using a `ClearStreamingOnly` or `DownloadAndClearStremaing` locator [AMS Streaming Locators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-streaming-locators-concept)?

You should be using the `DownloadAndClearStremaing` and use the generated video download URL.

Another option will be, as you already have your video in AMS, then it is saved in the AMS linked storage, you can generate a SAS Url for the video file and give that to VI to index.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, I solved the problem by configuring the streaming locator differently, I changed it to DownloadAndClearStremaing.

Thanks for your help.